# How to add new line in the output of a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Hi  I am trying to understand this:

So the output of this "file.txt" is as follows.. how do I make it look like:

looks like now :eatdogcatrat

want:
eat
dog
..

basically need to have each go to the next line.

```
my_locations = open("file.txt" , "w")
for mylist in channel:
    print(mylist)
    my_locations.write(mylist)
my_locations.close()
```

Comment: How about entering a linebreak?

Comment: I guess this is what you want `my_locations.write(mylist + '\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work!

```
channel = ['eat', 'dog', 'cat', 'rat']

my_locations = open("file.txt", "w")
for mylist in channel:
    print(mylist)
    my_locations.write(mylist + '\n') # to have each go to the next line.
my_locations.close()
```